# explanation on behaviour of `keyof` operator on generic types

Tags: typescript, generics

I've stumbled across a small issue, which I actually managed to solve. However, I am looking for an explanation why this is an issue in the first place.

Lets say we have the following types:

```
interface Base {
    name: string;
}

interface TypeA extends Base {
    foo: number;
} 

interface TypeB extends Base {
    bar: string;
}
```

And we have the following generic function:

```
const genericSet = <T>(obj: T, partial: Partial<T>) => ({ ...obj, ...partial });
const demo = genericSet({ b: '222', a: 111 }, { a: 333 });
/* works great */
```

but now let's call the function from within another generic function:

```
function doSomething<T extends Base>(obj: T) {
    const newObj = genericSet(obj, { name: 'a' }); //error!, argument {name: string} isn't assignable to Partial<T>
   ...
}
```

But if we define the function like this, basically just rewriting `Partial`

```
const genericSet2 = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, partial:{[key in K]?: T[key]} ) => ({ ...obj, ...partial });
```

Than everything works!

I'm just looking for information why. Intuitively I can guess it's something related when typescript actually computes types, but I would like a concrete explanation on why it works (If nothing else, just so I'm familiar with actual terms)

If you know of any relevant github issues/commits, it would also be great.